# Calling SQL Server stored procedure from powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a SQL Server stored procedure from PowerShell but I always get errors on parameters.

Stored procedure has 8 parameters, all with default values

```
@simchain   nvarchar
@idSimulation    int
@idCompany   varchar
@modelName  nvarchar
@simDate    datetime
@mySim           int
@statusFloor     int
@statusCap       int
```

From Management Studio I can call this procedure even without any parameter, so just executing `EXEC [dbo].[E_simulations]` works.

From PowerShell I create a connection and a command but I always get an error on missing parameters, for example

> Procedure or function 'E_simulations' expects parameter '@simchain', which was not supplied.

Here is my test code (just to test proper execution)

```
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString;
    $SqlCommand = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    $SqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[E_simulations]";
    $SqlConnection.Open();
    $returnedValue = $SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the stored procedure have default values for all parameters?  If not, I don't see how it could work from SSMS either.  The proper way to call a proc from Powershell (or any app code) is to specify only the proc name in the CommnadText and specify CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure.  You'll need to add required parameters.

Comment: Sure they have default values for each parameter.
I Tried to add `$SqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure` but have I now to add all parameters even if I want to use default values?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add parameters that have default values in the proc header.  I just ran a quick test of your code (StoredProcedure command type version) and it ran without error with no parameters added to the collection.  I get the error only if I remove a parameter default value.  Check to make sure you are connected to the same server and database as you did in SSMS.

Comment: So you are saying I am so stupid that I spend last 2 hours running this code against the production server instead of the test server where the procedure has been updated? Do you think I am so stupid?? Really??? Is that what you are saying????

Well... you're right... Thank you ;)

Comment: been there, done that :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have made quick test. I hope this will help

### Made test proc:

```
CREATE PROC doTest (
    @param1 INT = 1,
    @param2 VARCHAR(10) = 'xxx' 
)
AS
BEGIN

PRINT 'THIS ONE'
SELECT 1 As Data

END
```

### Find PowerShell code, which executes proc:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=ForTests;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "doTest"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

### Execute result gave this

```
Data
----
1
```

I done everything same what you wrote and I have result without assigning params

Comment: thank you for the complete test, finally the code seemed to be fine but I was testing wrong

Comment: how to execute the stored procedure if param1 and param2 are to be supplied explicitly?

Comment: @HappyLee use the Parameters property `$sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@hdr", $hdr)`. `$hdr` can be the value you want to pass and of course modify `@hdr` for the parameter expected